# Office 365 Image and Description

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365, modern-experience, sitepages

I have Requirement in which I need to show the Title, Description and Image is on left page?

For achieving this which web part I need to use in office 365 modern page?

If I can able to achieve this using OOTB, will I be able to add CSS style in it? If yes, Please let me know.

Comment: What exactly you want? Do you want to add text/image on SharePoint modern pages? Can you add any screenshot/image of how you want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Text web part** to add text/headings/paragraphs to your modern page.

Formatting options like styles, bullets, indentations, highlighting, and links are available. You can also paste images inline with text & add tables using this web part.

**Documentation**: [Text web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-text-tables-and-images-to-your-page-with-the-text-web-part-729c0aa1-bc0d-41e3-9cde-c60533f2c801)

---

You cannot add custom CSS styles using any OOTB web part.

---

**Update from comments**:

Microsoft is adding the ability to paste inline images into the Text web part so that images can be closer to text and so that text can wrap around images.

[Microsoft 365 Roadmap ID 85584](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ww/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=85584)

This feature is currently rolling out to [Targeted release tenants](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365?view=o365-worldwide) & soon will be available for all tenants (standard release/GA)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried the same scenario but I am not able to add image in the same we part of Text webpart.For image I need to select another we part which is image we part. All  I need to show like below :      Image    Title  -First Line . Second line is Description with Image . Will i able to achieve using Textwebpart?

Comment: Yes, soon you will be able to do it. Set up targeted release for yourself or wait for standard release/GA of new feature. check updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh! I hope it will be released this September 2021 right?Set up targeted release for yourself-This point i didn't get you . How to do that? Thank you so much!

Comment: Currently it is rolling out for targeted release tenants & for standard release tenants rollout will starts in early October. You can follow [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365?view=o365-worldwide) to setup targeted release.

Comment: Thank you so much Ganesh!